# Relating gridded data to polygons

Tags: python, raster, polygon, geopandas

I'm preparing weather forcing input data (dimensions of time/lat/long/variable) for a machine learning model to predict streamflow. I need area-weighted weather inputs (the weather data are on a grid) for each watershed (the polygons). I've done this in two steps:

1. **Compute a weight matrix**: I computed the portion that each grid cell has in each polygon. That gives me a matrix with the flattened grid cell ids on one dimension and the polygon ids on the other dimension. I did this using the geopandas overlay function.
2. **Take a dot product:** I do a dot product with the weight matrix and the weather drivers to get me the area-weighted average values of weather data for each polygon. I do this with Xarray and Dask.

This method has been working fine, but both steps are quite inefficient and it doesn't scale the best.

The vast majority of the grid cells for a given polygon have a weight of zero. I really need just the few grid cells that have a non-zero weight for the operation. Currently the dot product is performed on many many cells that are zeros. I think for this, I might be able to use Dask Delayed to loop through all my polygons, find the cells where the weights are non-zero, and then do the weighted average operation.

Less clear to me is how to do step 1 more efficiently. So many of the grid cells don’t intersect at all with the polygons, it seems like it could be more efficient just to do the overlay with only the parts of the grid that touch a given polygon, but I don’t know if that is possible. My polygon file is very large and will not fit into 32 GB when I read the layer from the GDB file.

This seems like a pretty common operation, *am I making this more complicated than I should be*?

*Is there a best practice for doing something like this*?

I know this is a bit vague, but I don’t think I know enough yet to make it more concrete.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be seeking a code review (for which there is the [codereview.se] without providing a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried.